# How to launch an application on Login(Not Startup) in Windows Server

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

Ok i am working on an application which is basically an activity monitor.

This application will automatically log out a user if there is no activity for some time. I have successfully done the logout part.

But i am trying to automatically start the application when another or same user logged in again.

I tried startup code but it only works when windows starts up.

```
 private void SetStartup()
        {
            RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
                ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

                rk.SetValue("My_App", Application.ExecutablePath);

        }
```

So is there any way to know when someone login in the system.
I am using winform and c#.
Let me know if someone needs more information
Thanks.

Comment: Check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423190/detect-windows-logon-attempts-programmatically-using-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423190/detect-windows-logon-attempts-programmatically-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

You can place a shortcut to your application in the "Startup" folder for all users. The location of this depends on your operating system.

Windows 10: press windows key+R, then type "shell:common startup". Put a shortcut to your application in here.

On Windows 7 it was at "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup".

If it's neither of those, add a comment...

Each time someone logs on, the application will be run.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information, but i was looking for something, more logical through coding. but anyways, thanks it is also a good solution.